# Externel depenancy/repo not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Live Development Server is listening on localhost:3000, open your browser on http://localhost:3000/ **

```
 92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\skycons\skycons.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:125:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:39:54)
    at Promise (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:69:49)s-webpack-plugin.js:69:49)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.map.fullPath (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:68:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at hook (E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:67:43)
```

Comment: please re-format your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'E:\SVN\Agilent-bildZoom\node_modules\skycons\skycons.js'` - webpack can't find this file, at the location stated in the error.

So check your node_modules and make sure you have referenced it correctly in your angular.json.